# How to declare a typdef in COM object idl?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sequence, typedef, idl

I have a COM object written in c++ ,I'm trying to declare a typedef for a sequence of a simple type (like int/bool) and access it in order to create a variable of its type in C#, where I added a reference to this COM object.
in the code i added here i wrote two options i tried to declare the typdef - but none of them is working for me - i cannot initialize a parameter of this type in my C# class.
here is the relevant part(Library) of my idl:

```
 [
    uuid(0EA0AD9B-9314-4480-8C69-22719C2EA9CF),
    version(1.0),]

library ATLProject9Lib
{
    typedef [public,uuid(9d286340-62c4-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3)]
    int aaa;

    typedef [public]
    double numberToAdd;


    struct BarStruct;
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [
        uuid(172B34D8-5D19-4635-B4AD-9171F522CA0A)      
    ]
    dispinterface _IScheduleEvents
    {
    properties:
    methods:
    };
    [
        uuid(34413E93-0916-4773-99C4-79163A44E4A0)      
    ]
    coclass Schedule
    {
        [default] interface ISchedule;
        [default, source] dispinterface _IScheduleEvents;
    };
};
```

Second issue: declaring a typdef of sequence of int for example:

```
typedef [public,uuid(9d286340-62c4-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3)]
sequence<int> aaa;

typedef [public]
double numberToAdd;
```

this code is not compiling.
i'm getting the following errors:

```
1>.\ATLProject9.idl(47): error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting a declarator or * near "<"
1>.\ATLProject9.idl(47): error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting ; or , near "<"
1>.\ATLProject9.idl(47): error MIDL2026: cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting compilation
```

What is the correct way to declare the typedef (for simple types and for sequence) in COM object?

Answer (score 4):

Little of what you are trying to do makes sense.  A *typedef* declares a **type** alias, just another name for a type.  It does not declare a variable,  not in C++ either.  Type aliases also don't survive Tlbimp, the type library importer you need to write C# code, type identity is a very big deal in the CLR and it has no mechanism to use two names to refer to the same type.  So the type library importer always decompiles the typedef to its original name.

Declaring variables is not possible in IDL.  COM uses a very strict [interface-based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming) paradigm that completely hides the implementation of a type.  The ultimate reason why it is good for interop code that can work between arbitrary language implementations.  A variable has way too much baggage, different languages implementations make different choices about the storage address and alignment of a variable.

Generics or templates are not possible either, nobody agrees how to implement such a feature.  Or don't implement it at all.  .NET generics are *drastically* different from C++ templates for example.

These restrictions are very much intentional. Only way to expose a variable you have declared in your C++ code is to write an interface with a property getter.

Comment: Hi Hans,
thank you for your answer.
however, i'm not sure we understood each other entirely.
i will explain what we trying to do: 
we want to cal an idl function from our C# code. this function gets as parameters some typedef variables. 
so we are trying to declare those typdef in our idl in order to be able to create them in our C|# and send them as parameters to this idl function.

Comment: You'll have to stop talking about "typedef variables", it is a completely meaningless phrase that does not help us help you.  You "create" something in a C# program with the `new` statement, that requires a coclass in your IDL.  Or you ask a COM object to create it for you, that requires a factory function that returns an interface pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the MIDL reference documentation.  Apparently there is no `sequence` keyword.  [This](http://marc.info/?l=ms-atl&m=103430606829339&w=2) suggests:

```
 typedef struct {
    int     foo;
 } IntStruct;

 typedef struct {
    int     cMax;
    [size_is(cMax)] IntStruct values[];
 } ListOfInts;
```

or

```
 typedef struct {
    int     foo;
 } IntStruct;

 typedef struct {
    int     cMax;
    [size_is(cMax)] IntStruct* values;
 } ListOfInts;
```

Do you really want types named `aaa` and `numberToAdd`?